# XSL Unable to perform XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml file with this structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="rental.xsl"?>
<rentalProperties>
<property available=“yes” contact=0459591009>
<type>house</type>
<price>price per week</price>
<numberOfBedrooms>1</numberOfBedrooms>
<numberOfBathrooms>1</numberOfBathrooms>
<garage>1</garage>
<description>A Description</description> 
</property>
</rentalProperties>
```

How do I go about transforming it? I have tried using this to start with. However it gives me a Unable to perform XSL transformation on your XML file. Open quote is expected for attribute "available" associated with an element type "property". error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="rentalProperties">
 <html>
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="property"/>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="property">
<p>
<xsl:variable name="curr_avail" select="@available"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$curr_avail"/> - 
<xsl:value-of select="."/> 
</p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: your input XML is not well-formed. To select variable, it should be prefixed by a `$`. `<xsl:value-of select="curr_avail"/>` s/b `<xsl:value-of select="$curr_avail"/>`

Comment: Yup I've tried that. What do you mean by my xml is not well-formed? Is it the structure

Comment: this `<property available=“yes” contact=0459591009>` s/b `<property available="yes" contact="0459591009">`

Comment: That's the very best error message I've ever seen from XML (and a lot of other systems too). What tool are you using, I'll want to switch to it if I can. Good luck.

Comment: With any XML editor, you should be able to grasp the well-formedness-related errors.

Comment: @shellter Both Xalan and Saxon will produce this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your input. Attribute values must be surrounded by quotes (either double or single). In your example, the value `yes` is surrounded by "smart quotes" (characters `&#8220;` and `&#8221;`) and the value `0459591009` is not quoted at all.

This makes your input not well-formed - which means it is not an XML document and cannot be processed by XSLT.